# Bounds on tail conditional expectation of random variable given variance

Tags: nonparametric, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, probability-inequalities, bounds

Given a random variable $X$ with CDF $F(X)$, mean $E(X)=0$, and variance $Var(X) =\sigma^2$, I would like to bound the tail conditional expectation where $X$ is in the tail with probability $1-p$:

$E(X|X\geq F^{-1}(p)) = \frac{1}{1-p}\int_{F^{-1}(p)}^\infty X dF(X)$

A nice way to get an upper bound is via a Chebyshev-type inequality: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177697276, which suggests:

$E(X|X\geq F^{-1}(p)) \leq \sigma \sqrt{\frac{p}{1-p}}$

But how can we get a lower bound? Intuitively, since $E(X) = 0$, we must have:

$E(X|X\geq F^{-1}(p)) \geq 0$

But that doesn't use the dispersion of the RV at all. Intuitively, if $\sigma$ is large and $E(X)=0$, the lower bound should be large, so the lower bound should grow with $\sigma$. But I have no idea how to formalize it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.